# Multiple opening and closing of modules using Prism crashes application

Tags: c#, exception, out-of-memory, prism

We have a PRISM Shell application with 10 to 15 modules.

When we open and close a module around 30 to 50 times, it crashes with the following exception:

> Message: HandlingInstanceID: c7d05b8e-9c0b-49d6-8dff-328ed4a4f78c An
>   exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred and was
>   caught.
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- 09/11/2014 17:03:46 Type : System.OutOfMemoryException, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>   Message : Nicht genügend Speicher verfügbar, um das Programm weiter
>   auszuführen. Source : PresentationCore Help link :  Data :
>   System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal TargetSite : Void
>   SyncFlush() HResult : -2147024882 Stack Trace :    bei
>   System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.Channel.SyncFlush()    bei
>   System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.CompleteRender()    bei
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.OnResize()    bei
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(WindowMessage msg,
>   IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    bei
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    bei
>   MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
>   IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    bei
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)    bei
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    bei
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler)    bei
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
>   numArgs)    bei MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)    bei
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)    bei
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DefWndProcWrapper(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr
>   wParam, IntPtr lParam)    bei
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)    bei
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr
>   wParam, IntPtr lParam)    bei
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.ShowWindow(HandleRef hWnd, Int32
>   nCmdShow)    bei System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
>   bei System.Windows.Window.Show()    bei
>   System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()    bei
>   Rodenstock.Consulting.ViewModel.ShellWindowViewModel.DisplaySplashScreen(Object
>   moduleName)    bei
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)    bei
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    bei
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    bei
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    bei
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(Object obj)

1. There is enough memory in the system.
2. There is enough RAM in the system.
3. The issue can be reproduced in 32 and 64 bit machines
4. The issue can be reproduced in Windows XP, Vista, 7 and 8
5. The end module releases known resources being used

Is there a MEF or PRISM resource that needs to be freed when a module is closed?

UPDATE:
There is a module catalog with all the modules. The bootstrapper loads the module catalog.

Comment: How are you implementing your module loading? As Prism offers multiple ways of doing this, it may help if we know slightly more about how you have structured your WPF application, module projects and then Prism configuration.

Comment: I also do not understand what you mean by unloading a module, from what I know, that is not a possible using Prism.